# Why is my custom event in Stencil not working? It's always undefined

Tags: javascript, stenciljs

```
@Event() valueSelected: EventEmitter<string>;

@Listen('selectedOptionValue')
selectedOptionValueFunc() { 
  console.log('event emitted')
}

fireCustomEvent() { 
    console.log(this.valueSelected)
    this.valueSelected.emit('selectedOptionValue')
  }

<select onChange={this.fireCustomEvent}></select>
```

`valueSelected` is always `undefined`, and I get the error: `Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'emit')`
Why? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you use an arrow function so that "this" is the correct context.  So something like this...

```
<select onChange={(event) => this.fireCustomEvent(event)}></select>
```